# jquery price not updating on delete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update price on delete button click. When I am clicking on add button it adding the field and updating the price. But on delete button it is only deleting field and price is not updating.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').on('click', function() {

     var maxfld=$('.acmp').length;
     var pricedl=500;

     if(maxfld<10)
     {
     $('#new_ac').append('<div id="" class="acmp">'+(++maxfld)+'  <p>ACCOMPANYING PERSON DETAILS (No access to Scientific Halls)</p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Accompany Full Name" required /><input type="text" name="mob" placeholder="Accompany Mobile Number" required /><br />Gender<br /><input name="gender" type="radio" value="male" required="required" /> Male<input name="gender" type="radio" value="female" required="required" /> Female</div>');
     }
     if(maxfld>9)
     {
        alert("Cannot add more accompany"); 

     }
     var totalp=(pricedl*maxfld);
       $('#amount').html(totalp);

  });

  $('#del').on('click', function() {
    $('.acmp:last-child').remove(); 
    var newp=totalp/maxfld;
      $('.price').html(newp);

  });
});
```

Comment: You need tot make your variables(`totalp,maxfld`) global. Now they are out of the scope of the second click function and it will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the below variables in delete block

```
 var maxfld=$('.acmp').length;
 var pricedl=500;
 var totalp=(pricedl*maxfld);
```

May be the below code will work

```
$('#del').on('click', function() {
    $('.acmp:last-child').remove(); 
    var maxfld=$('.acmp').length;
    var pricedl=500;
    var totalp=(pricedl*maxfld);
    var newp=totalp/maxfld;
    $('.price').html(newp);
  });
```

Comment: thanks Vineesh your code is working but little change will come. Thai is    $('#del').on('click', function() {
    $('.acmp:last-child').remove(); 
    var maxfld=$('.acmp').length;
    var pricedl=500;
    var totalp=(pricedl*maxfld);
    var newp=totalp/maxfld;
    $('.price').html(totalp);
  });

Answer (score 0):

You need tot make your variables(`totalp,maxfld`) global. Now they are out of the **scope** of the second click function and it will return `undefined`. Your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var maxfld = '';
var pricedl = '';
  $('#add').on('click', function() {

     maxfld = $('.acmp').length;
     pricedl = 500;

    if (maxfld < 10) {
      $('#new_ac').append('<div id="" class="acmp">' + (++maxfld) + '  <p>ACCOMPANYING PERSON DETAILS (No access to Scientific Halls)</p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Accompany Full Name" required /><input type="text" name="mob" placeholder="Accompany Mobile Number" required /><br />Gender<br /><input name="gender" type="radio" value="male" required="required" /> Male<input name="gender" type="radio" value="female" required="required" /> Female</div>');
    }
    if (maxfld > 9) {
      alert("Cannot add more accompany");

    }
    var totalp = (pricedl * maxfld);
    $('#amount').html(totalp);

  });

  $('#del').on('click', function() {
    $('.acmp:last-child').remove();
    var newp = totalp / maxfld;
    $('.price').html(newp);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me you need to remove the element after you get the value of `maxfld`

```
  $('#del').on('click', function() {
     var pricedl=500,
         maxfld=$('.acmp').length,
         totalp=(pricedl*maxfld);
    $('.acmp:last-child').remove(); 
    var newp=totalp/maxfld;
    $('.price').html(newp);

  });
```